# Getting wrong result from the inner functions call with the use of Kotlin co-routines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have created below function :

```
suspend fun isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId: String): Boolean {
    val count = appDatabase.userBatteriesDao().checkBatteryExists(batteryId)
    if (count > 0) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

which checks the particular record is exists in database or not.

**checkBatteryExists** is the dao method as below :

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DatabaseConstant.mUserBatteriesTable + " WHERE isDeleted = 0 and batteryId= :batteryId")
suspend fun checkBatteryExists(batteryId:String): Int
```

The Method **isBatteryExistsInLocal** is called from below function in my view model class.

```
fun isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId:String): Boolean {
    var isBatteryExistsInLocal = false
    scope.launch {
        isBatteryExistsInLocal =batteryRepository.isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId)
    }
    return isBatteryExistsInLocal
}
```

and the above method is calling from my fragment as below :

```
if (viewModel.isBatteryExistsInLocal(listNotifications[adapterPosition].batteryId)) {
```

But here, I am always getting **false** WHY ?

I have debugged and check that a record is exists in local database and also count variable is returns 1.

Then Why am getting **false** in above **if** condition ?

Please guide. What I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a coroutine, it is launched asynchronously, just like when you call a function that takes a callback. The coroutine is queued to start running, but the current function will possibly complete and return before that happens. Explanations of this issue are in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/) even though they are about API callbacks. It's exactly the same issue when launching a coroutine.

The only way to convert a suspend function into one you can call from outside a coroutine to get a return value synchronously is to do something like use `runBlocking` or calling `join` on your launched Job. But this is not an acceptable solution because it will block your main thread and cause stutters or the ANR error.

The correct solution is to use a coroutine higher up in your workflow so you can freely use suspend functions wherever you need to. For instance, if `isBatteryExistsInLocal` is something you need as part of a response to some button press, you should launch a coroutine in your button's click listener, and then your entire sequence of actions can freely include suspend function calls.

By the way, just a tip, you can simplfy your suspend function. Instead of using if/else to return true or false, you could simply put `return count > 0`.

Comment: ya used it but due to this issue changed it. Can you please help me to solve this out practically ? Thanks.

Comment: Wrap whatever code in you fragment that's calling `if (viewModel.isBatteryExistsInLocal(listNotifications[adapterPosition].batteryId)) {` in a coroutine. Make the view model function suspending and directly pass through the result of the DAO/repo function call. To launch a coroutine that works with views in a Fragment, you should use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch`.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you may have expected the function in `ViewModel` executes in following manner

```
fun isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId:String): Boolean {
    var isBatteryExistsInLocal = false
    scope.launch {
        // Everything inside will be executed async
        // outer function may already have returned by the time this completes
    }
    return isBatteryExistsInLocal
}
```

One way to fix this is to put the fragment code `(viewModel.isBatteryExistsInLocal(listNotifications[adapterPosition].batteryId))` inside a coroutine, which can be done as

```
lifecycleScope.launch{
    (viewModel.isBatteryExistsInLocal(listNotifications[adapterPosition].batteryId))
    // other code
}
```

And change your `ViewModel` function to be suspending as

```
suspend fun isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId:String): Boolean {
    return batteryRepository.isBatteryExistsInLocal(batteryId)
}
```